# Delete specific value in RecylerView in Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a database like below:

> +**Orders**
>
> ```
>     + uid(5mXErinXkQccgaoXWPeDtJZ8v852)
>           + push(randomkey1)
>                      id:
>                      date:
>                      time:
>                      price:
>                      address:
>           + push(randomkey2)
>                      ....
>
>           + push(randomkey3)
>                      ....
>           + push(randomkey4)
>     + uid(6xrinn1BcngPjzCWZUa0sUbTEnK2)
>           + push(randomkey5)
>           + push(randomkey6)
> ```

Under `Orders` node, there is a child `uid` which stores every users `id`. Under `uid` child, there are number of orders that every user can do, thats why I have used `push()` to generate random keys.

The question is, how can I delete for example `push(randomkey2)'???

```
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Orders").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).removeValue();
                                                                           notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

This code only removes specific `uid` but not specific value inside `uid`

Answer (score 0):

You did not specified the child of the "uid" node,
For example

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Orders")
.child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()) 
.child("randomkey2").removeValue();
```

Comment: Because it is randomly generated by push(). How do I know what is the value of push when it is generated. If it was exact randomkey I could have done such. But push is not same

Comment: use ...push().getKey(), this will return String of generated key